# How i can use json file in pugjs

Tags: pug

I'm Working in pugjs and I want to include json file in this, to use this file into loop elements like objects in pugjs.
Thanks

```
  var person = {
              'Abdelbaset Mansour': 'person1.jpg',
              'Ada Lovelace': 'person2.jpg',
              'Grace Murray': 'person3.jpg',
              'Mary Kenneth ': 'person4.jpg',
              'Radia Perlman': 'person5.jpg',
              'Steve Jobs': 'person6.jpg'
              };
          each val, index in person
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Have you tried a tutorial like [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_templating.htm) to become familiar with the basics of pug?

You need to pass the variable through in the ExpressJS route like this:

```
var person = {
          'Abdelbaset Mansour': 'person1.jpg',
          'Ada Lovelace': 'person2.jpg',
          'Grace Murray': 'person3.jpg',
          'Mary Kenneth ': 'person4.jpg',
          'Radia Perlman': 'person5.jpg',
          'Steve Jobs': 'person6.jpg'
};

res.render('my-template', { "person" : person });
```

Then in your template you just read the variable in your `each` statement like this:

```
table
  each val, index in person
    tr
      td= index
      td= val
```

Your JSON should also probably be reformed as an array, it makes no sense as an object.